# Compiling issue with Code::Blocks and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I followed the instructions of this site -> http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/setup-modern-opengl-3-and-4-with-glfw.html

Except that I don't find the libopengl.a

When I run this code: http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/beginner-learning-materials-for-modern.html

I'm using CodeBlocks and I get this errors:

```
||=== p4rogva, Debug ===|
||Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `Z7AppMainv':|
C:\Documents and Settings\marc\Escritorio\C++\p4rogva\main.cpp|145|undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'|
C:\Documents and Settings\marc\Escritorio\C++\p4rogva\main.cpp|147|undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'|
C:\Documents and Settings\marc\Escritorio\C++\p4rogva\main.cpp|149|undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'|
C:\Documents and Settings\marc\Escritorio\C++\p4rogva\main.cpp|151|undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'|
C:\Documents and Settings\marc\Escritorio\C++\p4rogva\main.cpp|153|undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'|
C:\Documents and Settings\marc\Escritorio\C++\p4rogva\main.cpp|197|undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(context.c.obj):context.c|| undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(context.c.obj):context.c|| undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(context.c.obj):context.c|| undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(context.c.obj):context.c|| undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__SetPixelFormat@12'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__wglMakeCurrent@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__wglCreateContext@4'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__wglShareLists@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__wglDeleteContext@4'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__wglMakeCurrent@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__wglMakeCurrent@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__SwapBuffers@4'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'|
C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'|
||=== Build finished: 30 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 2 seconds) ===|
```

Yes p4roba is the name of the project

Comment: Here is the path for libopengl32.a "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libopengl32.a"

Comment: i find libopengl32.a but i don't find libopengl.a

Comment: sorry,not libopengl.a you have to link libopengl32.a

Comment: That is mistake in blog.

Comment: okay i have linked opengl32.a but it still not work what I'm doing bad?

Comment: I changed the includes to:                                                #include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC                       and now I get the following errors: undefinded reference to glfw, imp_, gl, all these not exactly as I can type the 37 errors

Comment: Do you follow the note of that blog "Note: make sure that glew32s.lib must be top of the list of linker."

Comment: yes, sure, glew32s.lib is in the top.

Comment: Have you tried linking against both libopengl32.a and libglu32.a?